# NullPointerException but why?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, el

I have class where

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StateOfDispatchToWD stateOfDispatchToWD = StateOfDispatchToWD.NONE;
```

And getter and setter:

```
public StateOfDispatchToWD getStateOfDispatchToWD() {
    return stateOfDispatchToWD;
}

public void setStateOfDispatchToWD(StateOfDispatchToWD stateOfDispatchToWD) {
    this.stateOfDispatchToWD = stateOfDispatchToWD;
}
```

and method:

```
public boolean isSuccessfullySentToWD() {
    return zoj.getStateOfDispatchToWD() == StateOfDispatchToWD.SUCCESSFULLY_DISPATCH;
}
```

and call it from JSF:

```
            <p:outputLabel value="OK"
                           rendered="#{Z.isSuccessfullySentToWD()}"/>
```

and sometimes I get:

```
[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle]
javax.el.ELException: //content/resources/zo.xhtml @240,92 rendered="#{Z.isSuccessfullySentToWD()}":
java.lang.NullPointerException:
javax.faces.FacesException:
javax.el.ELException: //content/resources/zo.xhtml @240,92 rendered="#{Z.isSuccessfullySentToWD()}":
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

but why? I'm afraid I don't understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because `Z` was null?

Comment: Exception is on line "    return zoj.getStateOfDispatchToWD() == StateOfDispatchToWD.SUCCESSFULLY_DISPATCH;
"

Comment: No it isn't, Read the stack trace. It is in the EL, in the expression `#{Z.isSuccessfullySentToWD()}`. There is nothing to suggest you got any further.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can't tell if this is a duplicate without more information. Please provide a runnable example - specifically show exactly how `zoj` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the scope of Z is wrong, try to put it in session or application scope

Comment: It can be if it is in request scope and request is expired, or even if it is in session scope and session is expired

Comment: Z is @ViewScoped (javax.faces.view)

Comment: And I use it in too:

 <p:commandButton value="ss" immediate="true" update="@form"
                                         disabled="#{Z.isSuccessfullySentToWD()}"
                                         action="#{Z.sentZToX()}"/>

Comment: Hmm, than what is zoj object? maybe you need to change it with this.

Comment: Do you have this annotation on top of you managed bean: @Named(value = "Z") or your managed bean is calles Z?

Comment: I use @Named, and name is Z

Comment: what is zoj object? maybe you need to change it with this -> return this.getStateOfDispatchToWD() == StateOfDispatchToWD.SUCCESSFULLY_DISPATCH;

Comment: zoj is entity/model

Comment: But what, is it proprety or you reffered to the Z object ?

Comment: Z is ViewScoped, and Zoj is variable in Z

Comment: and Zoj have variable  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StateOfDispatchToWD stateOfDispatchToWD = StateOfDispatchToWD.NONE;

Comment: how did you initializate zoj in Z?

Comment: You need to initializate Zoj in default contructor of Z or immedietly like Zoj zoj=new Zoj();

Comment: private ZOJ zoj;
    public ZOJ getZoj() {
        return zoj;
    }

    public void setZoj(ZOJ zoj) {
        this.zoj = zoj;
    }
and in init I call 
    public void setDocument(ZOJ document) {
        setZoj(document);
    }

Comment: First thing, check if your init is even ever called and also init needs to be called in default contrcutor because it is not you who create Z object in view scope

Comment: Do you maybe use spring or you using JEE?

Comment: use Jakarta - JEE

Comment: check if your init is even ever called and also init needs to be called in default contrcutor because it is not you who create Z object in view scope

Comment: Is called, when I open the view and are loaded data from DB to Zoj

Comment: I think that the best is to call init in default contrcutor of Z so you will not have the problem, bacause loading data from DB takes to long and you view is already initialized and because you zoj is still null